# Find total number of elements of order 20 in the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z^*_{100}$

Tags: group-theory, congruences

How can I find all the elements of order $20$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z^*_{100}$.

$[7]\in \mathbb Z^*_{100}$.
$7^4\equiv 1\pmod{100}$. So order of $[7]=4$. But how can I find all those elements of order $20$ in $ \mathbb Z^*_{100}$?.
Are there any theorem of formula to find order of an element?
Than you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By chinese remainder theorem $\mathbb Z_{100}^*\cong \mathbb Z_4^*\times \mathbb Z_{25}^*$.

An element of the latter subgroup $(a,b)$ has order $lcm(|a|,|b|)$ where $|a|$ and $|b|$ are the orders in $\mathbb Z_4^*$ and $\mathbb Z_{25}^*$. So if $(|a|,|b|)=20$ we must have $|b|=20$.

Of course it is a well known theorem $\mathbb Z_{p^\alpha}^*$ is cyclic for $p$ an odd prime.

So the pair $(a,b)$ has order $20$ if and only if $|b|=20$. Since $\mathbb Z_{25}^*\cong \mathbb Z_{20}$ there are $\varphi(20)=8$ suitable options for $b$ (cyclic groups have $\varphi(n)$ elements of order $n$)and hence $2$ options for $a$ ($\mathbb Z_{4}^*$ has two elements).

Hence there are $16$ elements of order $20$.

If you want to find them all then one way to do it is by finding a generator for $\mathbb Z_{25}^*$

Lets try with $2$, we get $2,4,8,16,7,14,3,6,12,24,23,21,17,9,18,11,22,19,13,1$

So in fact $2$ generates. From here we can see the groups as:

$2,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5\dots 2^{20}$, of course we want the elements in which the exponent is relatively prime with $20$. So we want $2^{1},2^3,2^7,2^9,2^{11},2^{13},2^{17},2^{19}$ which corresponds to $2,8,3,12,17,22,13$.

Each of these values for $b$ shall give us two congruence classes $\bmod 100$ of order $20$, they are $(1,b)$ and $(3,b)$ respectively. It is clear these numbers are $b,b+50$ if $b$ is odd and $b+25,b+75$ if $b$ is even. Doing this for each $b$ is all that remains, lets do it:

$27,77$ results from $b=2$ and $33,83$ result from $b=8$. The other $12$ are:

$3 ,53, 37, 87, 23, 73, 17, 67, 47, 97, 13, 63$. So these are the $16$ elements.

Comment: Can you show please, how to find elements such that $(n,100)=5$.

Comment: I told you, they are the odd multiples of $5$ that are not multiples of $25$. So they are all the numbers ending in $5$ between $1$ and $100$ except $25$ and $75$.

Comment: @dREaM: can you explain how is this group cyclic?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the dot above the $\mathbb Z$

Comment: It should be fine now

Comment: @dREaM: I think OP is asking for all elements of order $20$ , Not number of elements of order $20$. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, title was missleading. Done

Comment: @dREaM Now, you have explained it beautifully :) {+1}